Using unittest with pandas
I am new to unit tests in general and Python's unittest in particular.
When trying to validate a pandas dataframe df, I typically:

Check whether df is empty (using one of the methods detailed here).
Check whether df contains the expected columns.

I would like to standardize the way I am running these tests.
The pandas documentation lists available assert functions (assert_frame_equal, assert_series_equal, assert_index_equal and assert_extention_array_equal), but as far as I understand I cannot use those to run the aforementioned tests.
I came up with the following class:
import pandas as pd
import unittest
class DataFrameTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_if_dataframe_is_empty(self,df):
        self.assertTrue(len(df) > 0)

    def test_if_dataframe_contains_required_columns(self,df,columns):
        self.assertTrue(set(df.columns.to_list()) == set(columns))

The following snippet...
data = [[412256, 142193, 4], [644402, 5208768 ,25]]
columns = ['easting', 'northing','elevation']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
dataframetestcase = DataFrameTestCase()
dataframetestcase.test_if_dataframe_is_empty(df)
dataframetestcase.test_if_dataframe_contains_required_columns(df, columns)

...does not return any error.
On the other hand, passing an empty dataframe df or a different columns list raises an AssertionError: False is not true error.
Is this the way to proceed or is there a built-in set of pandas or unittest assert functions that handle this in a better way?

"...does not return any error". Well should it? Isn't that a passing snippet? Or are you trying to say that you want better error messages on the failing case than just "False is not true"?

Thanks for your reply @TeemuRisikko. The snippet behaves as expected. I was simply wondering whether that was a better (built-in?) way to run unit tests in pandas.

I'll try to show you a standard use of unittest (at least on my opinion) for your goal.
The following is your code with some changes. The name of the script is: pandas_test_routine.py:
import pandas as pd
import unittest

data = [[412256, 142193, 4], [644402, 5208768, 25]]
columns = ['easting', 'northing', 'elevation']

# this is a not desired data because is empty
data_empty = []

class DataFrameTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # the method setUp() is executed before any test
    def setUp(self):
        self.data = data
        self.columns = columns
        self.sut = pd.DataFrame(data=self.data, columns=self.columns)

    def test_if_dataframe_IS_NOT_empty(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.sut.empty)

    def test_if_dataframe_CONTAINS_required_columns(self):
        self.assertTrue(set(self.sut.columns.to_list()) == set(self.columns))

    def test_if_dataframe_IS_empty(self):
        self.data = data_empty
        self.sut = pd.DataFrame(data=self.data, columns=self.columns)
        # We can set a custumize message error by failIf()
        self.failIf(self.sut.empty, "data frame is empty")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

To execute the tests you can do (in a terminal):
/path/to/interpreter/python /path/to/script/pandas_test_routine.py

While the first and the second test are successfully executed, the execution of the third test stops with the following error:
AssertionError: True is not false : data frame is empty

Note that the instruction failIf() is deprecated but I think it is suited for your needs.
Method setUp()
Useful the method setUp() of the class TestCase: it is execute before the execution of every tests.
In your case setUp() create the object sut with the correct data.
Note: sut stands for System Under Test (in your case is an instance of the class DataFrame).
Method unittest.main()
The snippet of code:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

executes all methods of the class DataFrameTestCase with the name which starts with test

Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I had no clue that unittest.main() would execute all "test" methods automatically! Also setUp() will come in handy.

Interestingly, I added print statements in each method (print(TEST1)) and noticed that unitttest.main() does not execute them in sequential order.

Yes I know this. In the documentation you can find the rule used by unittest for selecting the set of tests to execute. I didn't remember anything about the execution orde. If you want check it yourself.
